# Close vote seems to have disappeared

Tags: support, vote-to-close

About a week ago I voted to close [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7025/why-cant-i-connect-my-private-fb-account-with-twitter) as a duplicate.

I've stumbled across the question again and the auto-generated comment "possible duplicate..." is still there but the close vote is gone.

Has a moderator removed this close vote? If so, why not the comment also.  If the close vote hasn't been removed where has it gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close votes decay away over time. I think it's four days. So if no-one else sees the vote and/or they disagree by doing nothing the post will remain open.

While the vote decays the comment remains.

If you still think the question needs closing flag it for moderator attention.

In this case I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: Out of interest - is there any particular (stand out) reason that you don't think its a duplicate?

Comment: The one you link to is asking "why" the accounts can't be linked (others apparently are), while the other question is looking for a way. I suppose the answers might be the same in both cases. I'm willing to be convinced.

Comment: They can be linked - just not as easily and as obvious as corporate pages. I guess posting an answer saying that they can be linked and pointing them to the "dup" question would be another option. The only way anyone would find out "why" was if a Facebook staff member posted the reasons why - which is probably not going to happen.

Comment: @Barry - I see your point. Post the answer anyway as I still think that they shouldn't be duplicates. It's a grey area.